# MOSS file upload size limit for a specific site/library

Tags: moss

Can we set a different upload size limit for a site or a document library in MOSS 2007? From different I mean different from the global setting that we set from Central admin.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not configurable on a list by list basis.  It is only configurable on a per web application basis.